# Dynamics CRM 2016: Data import stuck in to submitted status

Tags: data-import, dynamics-crm-2016

I've admin rights to dynamics crm 2016 (on-prem) and I am trying to import a data file that contain around six records only. But it stuck at submitted status reason and nothing get imported in CRM. I restarted CRM ASync service but no luck.

I would like to seek advice from experts.

Comment: Check the basics:
1) Async Service enabled
2) No errors in event viewer
3) User configured to the async service is a service user (not in CRM)

Comment: And if none of that works, restart the Async service again (3rd times a charm) and seek advice from MS Support.

Answer (score 0):

Although there can be many reasons for this issue, the most common issue is that the async process for that particular environment may be disabled. You can find the exact reason by following the below steps:

1. In 'Advanced Settings' go to 'System Jobs'
2. Select 'My System Jobs' in the View filter
3. Click on the appropriate job from the list
   [You will see something like this. Expand the 'Details' section to view the description of the problem you are facing. In this case it is: "The async operation was skipped because the org is in “Disable Background Processing” mode."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Nu4a.png)
4. One of the reasons when background processing is disabled is when the selected environment is in  'Administration Mode'.
5. You can check whether your environment is in admin mode by going to https://admin.powerplatform.microsoft.com/ and checking your environment settings. If you want to keep it in Admin mode, you can turn on the 'Background Jobs' like this [Turn on the slider for 'Background Jobs'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiIcl.png)

After this, your jobs should be running.

If this is not the case for you, there can be other reasons like the mapping of the fields is wrong, or mandatory field is missing etc., which can be rectified during the import steps by manually mapping the correct fields from your Excel file and choosing the ignore or alternate values for drop down fields etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).